# Radius Search PHP, MYSQL and Google Maps

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, google-maps

Im searching a database with the latitude and longitude of a location. I want to retrieve all of the locations within a certain radius.

I then encode the returned results into a JSON and retrieve the data using ajax, however I get an undefined error meaning that there is no data returned from the database.

Can anybody see where im going wrong?

Heres my query

```
$sql="SELECT *, ACOS( SIN( RADIANS( `lat` ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( $fLat ) ) + COS( RADIANS( `lat` ) )
* COS( RADIANS( $fLat )) * COS( RADIANS( `lng` ) - RADIANS( $fLon )) ) * 6380 AS `distance`
FROM `markers`
WHERE ACOS( SIN( RADIANS( `lat` ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( $fLat ) ) + COS( RADIANS( `lat` ) )
    * COS( RADIANS( $fLat )) * COS( RADIANS( `lng` ) - RADIANS( $fLon )) ) * 6380 < 10
    ORDER BY `distance`";


    $result = mysql_query($sql);

    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) $rows[] = $r;

    echo json_encode($rows);
```

Comment: Suggestion: Try the query without the WHERE clause (or a simpler WHERE clause) and see if you can get some results first.  Divide and conquer to isolate the source of the issue. looking at the distances that result might be informative.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.Just removed the where clause and still got nothing, any other ideas?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM markers` perhaps?

Comment: Information: I just manually replaced the lat/long values with -32.9 and 87.01 and got some hits on a database I have that has latitude and longitude fields.  The query seems to be sound in SQL. Did you echo out the SQL query to see if the incoming variables are at fault?

Comment: Just put some meaningful values in the query and still nothing. Dont wanna sound an idiot, but how do i 'echo out the sql'

Comment: can you try this incase it is a connection error, which would result in an empty resultset, which would give you an empty json object. $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: just added that in and i still have an empty object. I dont know if this is relavant but ive just copied the google tutorial https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch#findnearsql and this also returns empty even though ive created a new table and imported their data. Could this be related?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not much help with trig or SQL, I've just seen enough Google maps questions to point you to this tutorial:

https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch#findnearsql

There is a query for finding spots by distance in a radius that you can try, hope it works for you.

Use 3959 (in miles) or 6371 (in km)

Comment: Thanks, ive already looked at that tutorial. And copied all the code in (changing the relavant bits) and that returns an empty xml document .

Comment: Sorry it wasn't helpful. If you leave out the `distance < 25` part, or increase it a lot, say thousands, I figure it should return several markers. If not, could it be a type mismatch in the database? The math might be processed incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
$sql="SELECT * , ACOS( SIN( RADIANS( 'lat' ) ) * SIN( RADIANS( $fLat ) ) + COS( RADIANS( 'lat' ) ) * COS( RADIANS( $fLat )) * COS( RADIANS( 'lng' ) - RADIANS( $fLon )) ) * 6380 AS distance FROM 'markers'
WHERE  distance < 10
ORDER BY distance";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

$rows = mysql_fetch_assoc($result));

echo json_encode($rows);  `
```